# Converting the usual 'dot' representation of hue in relplot into an equivalent color bar

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that contains data on gene expression levels ('exp') and perecent of cells expressing each gene ('pct') for each of 14 clusters and 20 genes:

```
    pct         gene    cluster   exp

0   36.654545   Gene1   0     -0.842864
1   8.145455    Gene2   0     -0.197432
2   10.690909   Gene3   0     -0.171912
3   17.745455   Gene4   0     -0.175636
4   16.654545   Gene5   0     -0.209753
... ... ... ... ...
782 88.505747   Gene16  13    2.500000
783 52.873563   Gene17  13    -0.532232
784 100.000000  Gene18  13    1.877539
785 42.528736   Gene19  13    0.399588
786 37.931034   Gene20  13    -0.402967
280 rows × 4 columns
```

I'm trying to show 'exp' and 'pct' values for each cluster-gene combination.

I created a dotplot showing the 2 variables using hue (='exp') and size (='pct').

As 'exp' values are Z-scores, I used a diverging palette and hue_norm so that the middle color is 0 (equals the mean).

The results I got are as I wished for, but it is more common to show the legend of expression levels as a continuous color bar rather than discrete points.

I'd be grateful if someone could help me obtain the same legend shown now as individual points in a continuous cbar.

This is the code I used and the resulting plot:

```
sns.relplot (data=dotplot_refined, x="cluster", y="gene", hue="exp", size="pct",sizes=(20, 200),hue_norm=(-1.5,1.5),palette="RdYlBu_r",aspect=1.8,height=6)
```

[image: The plot I got]

*** Follow-up question:
I apologize if this is the wrong way for a follow-up question. I tried commenting to the answer provided to my original question but the number of cahracters allowed is extremely low.

I've read all matplotlib documentation related to the answer, but still cannot seem to undrstand exactly what is going on here. Specificalyl, I don't understand fully the colors.Normalize function and how it relates to the hue_norm argument of seaborn's relplot function.

My goal is to present my numerical data using a color bar. The values in my dataset run from -1.6 to 2.5, so to reduce the effect of outliers I am trying to show only the values from -1 to 1 with anything above or below these recieving the same color as the max/min values, respectively.

This is the relevant part of the code that I used, first generating a custom palette from grey to red, then setting a Normalize object from -1 to 1, and setting the clip argement to True, and then applying that object inside the hue_norm argument of relplot:

````
```python
palette = sns.color_palette("blend:#d7d7d7,#b8151d", as_cmap=True)
norm = Colors.Normalize(-1,1,clip=True)
g = sns.relplot(data=dotplot, y="cluster", x="gene", hue="exp", 
size="pct", hue_norm=norm, palette=palette)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=palette, norm=norm), 
shrink=cbar_shrink)
```
````

I would like to ask:

1. Just to make sure I understand, does Colors.Normalize take a palette and 'stretch' it between the 2 values? in this case between -1 and 1, so that the edge colors are set to -1 and 1 respectively?
2. How is this different from providing the same values to hue_norm?
3. I indeed see that any value below min or above max got the edge color, but surprisingly, I got the same result when clip was set to False (the exact same colors for each point, although I expected that values that are above 1 or below -1 will get stronger/weaker colors).

Thanks for anyone who might help me understand!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a colorbar from the colormap and norm.  And copy the size indicators to a new legend.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dotplot_refined = pd.DataFrame({'gene': [f'Gene{i}' for i in np.tile(np.arange(20) + 1, 14)],
                                'cluster': np.repeat(np.arange(14), 20)})
dotplot_refined['exp'] = np.random.normal(0, 1, len(dotplot_refined))
dotplot_refined['pct'] = np.clip(np.random.normal(40, 30, len(dotplot_refined)), 0, 100)

palette = "RdYlBu_r"
norm = plt.Normalize(-1.5, 1.5)
cbar_shrink = 0.7
g = sns.relplot(data=dotplot_refined, x="cluster", y="gene",
                hue="exp", size="pct", sizes=(20, 200), hue_norm=norm, palette=palette,
                aspect=1.8, height=6)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=palette, norm=norm), shrink=cbar_shrink)
pos = cbar.ax.get_position()  # get the original position
# align the colorbar with the top of the main ax
cbar.ax.set_position([pos.x0, pos.y0 + pos.height * (1 - cbar_shrink), pos.width, pos.height])

# get information from the generated figure legend, and extract the information about the sizes
handles = g.legend.legendHandles
labels = [t.get_text() for t in g.legend.texts]
ind = labels.index('pct')  # find index of the 'pct' subtitle
g.legend.remove()
# add the reduced legend
g.ax.legend(handles=handles[ind + 1:], labels=labels[ind + 1:], title='pct',
            loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.035, 0), frameon=False)
g.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.regplot with colorbar]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works beautifully!!
I'm still a beginner and this actually my first time in SO, so really appreciate your time.

I do not understand much of your code since I have mostly learnt seaborn syntax but hopeto catch up so I can gain such masterful capabilities.

Thanks!!